# Possible to inflate android spinner layout extended by ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-inflate

Is it possible to inflate `Textview` from `@android:id/text1` ?
I don't want to create own layout, I would like just get a little modified text.

Here is my code:

First, I created variable to store data

```
private List<HashMap<String, String>> dataCities = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
//Hashmap with keys and values
//id - 0
//name - default
```

Second, I created custom adapter in onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//...
Spinner citiesSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.city_sp);
citiesAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, dataCities);
citiesSpinner.setAdapter(citiesAdapter);
}
```

Third, I created my listener. It works but after calling notifyDataSetChanged nothing happens. Why?

```
@Override
public void onRequestJsonResponded(RequestType type, JSONArray array) {
    //my enum type
    switch (type) {
        case cities:
            //returns hashmap in arraylist, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> ...
            dataCities = parseJSonArray(array);
            Log.d(TAG, "End of parsing");
            citiesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        case mark:
            //...
            break;
        case model:
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is my custom arrayadapter

```
private class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<HashMap<String, String>> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        tv.setText(getItem(position).get("name"));

        return v;

    }

}
```

Could someone tell me why do I get blank spinner data? (Spinner is empty). And how I get modified text without creating new layout? I would like just to use sherlock spinner item layout. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, the list in your adapter is not the same as the list that you retrieved:

```
        //In here you update your activity's list to the returned values
        dataCities = parseJSonArray(array);
        Log.d(TAG, "End of parsing");
        //But the adapter is using the original value of dataCities (new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>() )
        citiesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Since your adapter depends on ArrayAdapter, the easiest solution might be to just create a new adapter when the data is received.

Comment: please, could you tell me why notifyDataSetChanged doesn't work here?

Comment: Errr "Simple, the list in your adapter is not the same as the list that you retrieved." It's explained in depth in the code snippet?